# USER_TAB_PARTITIONS Query Runs Incredibly Slow

Tags: oracle, performance, partitioning, catalog-views

I seem to be seeing incredibly slow (5-10 seconds) to run a query against USER_TAB_PARTITIONS (Oracle) intermittently.  When I do an explain plan on :

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='MY_TABLE'
```

One of the steps shows a Nested Loops/Merge Join (Option = CARTESIAN) operation against TABPART$.  The TABPART$ system table shows it has been analyzed in the last day.  Is there a known problem with 11.2 and USER_TAB_PARTITIONS?

By the way, I am running Oracle v11.2.0.1

Comment: If you've analyzed system tables manually, rather than using `GATHER_DICTIONARY_STATS` (which just analyzes a subset of tables that need it), you have messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found in support.oracle.com:

`Bug 8334498 Query on DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS does full table scan on TABPART$`

This bug fixed in version 11.2.0.2.